# CountUp is not defined

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use this countUp.js library to achieve that nice rising number animation. I found a cdn and put it in my code and followed a tutorial on how to use it.

**Repo** https://github.com/inorganik/countUp.js

**CDN** https://cdnjs.com/libraries/countup.js/2.0.0

**Tutorial** https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cJ-T8Gb12lI

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/countup.js/2.0.0/countUp.min.js" integrity="sha512-E0zfDwA1CopT4gzJmj9tMpd7O6pTpuybTK58eY1GwqptdasUohyImuualLt/S5XvM8CDnbaTNP/7MU3bQ5NmQg==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="counters">
    <p id="counter1">0</p>
  </div>

  <script>
      let demo = new CountUp('counter1', 0, 100);
      demo.start();
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

This code gives me `Uncaught ReferenceError: CountUp is not defined` in the console.

Comment: Why are you passing `100` instead of `{}` as the *options* parameter? RTM: https://github.com/inorganik/countUp.js#usage

Comment: PS: Don't use `<script>` in a render-blocking manner. Try always to place any `<script>` tag right before the closing `</body>` tag (not inside `<head>`).

Comment: @Roko C. Buljan, I guess this would make an answer

Comment: PS: why `let` instead of `const`? [RTM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) Don't *just* use `let` as a replacement for `var` - ditch `var` where feasible, but learn about the difference.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan wondering why you rolled back my edit which actually demonstrated the problem?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Can you explain a bit more what you mean? I've always placed CDNs in the head.

Comment: @nandesuka If you google for `render blocking` one of the many: https://web.dev/render-blocking-resources/

Comment: @Jamiec no improvement whatsoever (You can always create an answer with a runnable snippet - if that helps) - and was making the comments section partially obsolete. Feel welcome to undo - I'll not re-rollback.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Okay if I'm not mistaken, would adding defer in the script tag allow me to keep it in the head?

Comment: @nandesuka the issue I'm seeing seems to be that cdnjs server a Module, not a globally `window.CountUp` available method. Pelase read: https://github.com/inorganik/CountUp.js#including-countup

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As described in the [docs on including Countup](https://github.com/inorganik/CountUp.js#including-countup) the CDN version is served as a module.

One option is to use the non-module [umd](http://jargon.js.org/_glossary/UMD.md) version

- this is what they do in their [demos](https://inorganik.github.io/countUp.js/)

```js
const c = new countUp.CountUp("counter1", 500)
c.start()
```

```html
<script src="https://inorganik.github.io/countUp.js/dist/countUp.umd.js"></script>
<div id="counters">
  <p id="counter1">0</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have not used the right source for the countup library. Try this:

```js
let demo = new CountUp('counter1', 0, 100)
demo.start()
```

```html
<script
  src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/countup@1.8.2/countUp.js"
></script>
<div id="counters">
  <p id="counter1">0</p>
</div>
```