# How to properly implement countUp.js?

Tags: javascript

I'd like to add a simple counter to my webpage using `countUp.js`.

Here is my code:

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <link rel="stylesheet"
          href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-xOolHFLEh07PJGoPkLv1IbcEPTNtaed2xpHsD9ESMhqIYd0nLMwNLD69Npy4HI+N"
          crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Test</title>

</head>
<body>

    <div class="container-fluid">

        <div class="row justify-content-center">
             <div id="test-counter" class="col-8 border">
                0
             </div>
        </div>

    </div>



<!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - >
<     Load the JavaScript Libraries      >
<- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->

<!--  own JavaScript  -->
    <script src="js/countUp.js"></script>

   
<!-- CountUp.js library -->
    <script
            src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/countup@1.8.2/countUp.js"
    ></script>

   
</body>
</html>
```

**js/countUp.js file**

```
const c = new countUp.CountUp('test-counter', 100)
c.start()
```

I tried to implement this according to the advice given on [CountUp is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65773705/countup-is-not-defined), but it's not working.

Questions:

1. Is my file structure correct?  (i.e. do I instantiate an object `c` and call it from within a separate `countUp.js` file (which itself is imported into the `index.html` file?
2. Am I importing `countUp.js` correctly from its source? (I'm new to JavaScript)
3. Could I just take the contents of https://github.com/inorganik/countUp.js/blob/master/dist/countUp.js and drop that into a file in my project?  (then reference this file locally)

Thanks in advance for any help you can give!

Comment: The other question has a working solution that uses countUp.umd.js instead of countUp.js.  Does that work for you?

Comment: It did not.  Is my file structure correct?

Comment: I would move YOUR script tag below the countUp script tag. Otherwise your script is trying to refer to something that hasn't loaded yet.

Comment: The documentation notes that "CountUp is distributed as an ES6 module because it is the most standardized and most widely compatible module for browsers, though a UMD module is also included."  You want to follow the [Example with vanilla js](https://github.com/inorganik/countUp.js#example-with-vanilla-js)  Yet, the confusion is understandable as the documentation is not written in a clear, easy to follow, way.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments you cant use anything from a script that was not yet parsed (the browser parse the html file from top to bottom line after line with some exceptions).

1. The conventional names for classes start with upper-case letter and you try to use the `new` key word on countUp instead of CountUp.
2. In the html file first import CountUp.js library and after that use your script countUp.js.
3. Yes you can copy or download the script CountUp.js to your project and use it "locally".